# Unknown option -pthread in LD

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, c, posix, clang

This is a follow up from [this](https://github.com/ljubobratovicrelja/ffmpeg-d/issues/1#issuecomment-201181709) issue on Github.

Basically, on OS X El Capitan, I get this message:

```
ld: unknown option: -pthread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
--- errorlevel 1
```

As can be seen from the link above, this is from linking ffmpeg-d through dub to a d project.

But *why* is it happening? OS X is Posix, and I would think it'd support *posix threads* but it doesn't seem to, at least in my case. I tried looking online  for information but there is not much documentation and it seems that it is it not supported on many systems.

Is that true on OS X?

And how should I circumvent this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found an answer. I don't know if this is intended, but I had to run (while building ffmpeg) `./configure --disable-pthread`. That fixed it, at least for now. I'm not sure if it's supposed to run without threads. Furthermore, `./configure --help` shows `disable pthreads [autodetect]` which seems to indicate that it's meant to be detected automatically.